# Create tag and make local changes, then rebase against public branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

We have a situation in which (for this example) we have a straight line of development that is preparing for a release:

```
A --> B --> C --> D
                  ^ HEAD
```

We decide that commits `C` and `D` are too forward-thinking, and we want to do the release from `B`. We have a tool that will go back and tag `B` as our release version, say `product-1.0.0`, and will then update a number of versioning files to `1.1.0`, or whatever version is next.

**The problem is the creation of the tag, and the tweaking of the files, is an atomic operation.** We can change this, but it's a little bit more hassle.

So while the tag needs to point at `B`, we want our file changes to be popped into a new commit. What we currently have:

```
      v detached, tagged, with local changes
      |
A --> B --> C --> D
                  ^ HEAD
```

But, if we commit from our current point, we end up with:

```
       /--> E (a 'lost' commit)
      /
A --> B --> C --> D
      ^ tag       ^ HEAD
```

What is the easiest way, either from the "detached with local changes" point, or from the "lost commit" point, to merge either our local changes, or our new commit, to the public branch so that it looks like:

```
A --> B --> C --> D --> E
      ^ tag             ^ NEW HEAD
```

The commits `C` and `D`, as well as the entire branch, is public - so we can't really inject commit `E` between `B` and `C`. It's okay if those commits (`C` and `D`) exist as 'newer' `1.0.0` versions of the product we're releasing, we just want to create a new commit on top of the current `HEAD`.

**Is there a better way than stashing, checking out `HEAD`, then popping and committing?**

Comment: I think you mean `master` and not `HEAD` in you examples. `HEAD` in `git` is not a branch, but something that points to a branch, namely the one you currently have checked out.

Comment: Nope, I do mean `HEAD`. Our releases take place from one of 3 branches, depending on whether they're major, minor, or patch releases. So I was just looking for a way to get to the `HEAD` of any of those branches.

Comment: What does "HEAD" mean in your terminology? The latest commit of a branch (like in Subversion)?

Comment: Sorry - I thought that `HEAD` was always the tip of the current branch you were on. But that's not quite the case. I still don't mean `master`, which is a branch that may or may not exist in a repository - is there a Git term for the tip of the current branch? (Besides just the name of the branch itself?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer show a workflow which uses local branches as an alternative to the stash mechanism. This is the approach I prefer myself.

I'm going to assume that:

- Your public branch head is called `master`
- This "atomic operation" is a script used for making releases.
- The release tag (`product-1.0.0`) needs to point to B in the end.
- The release commit (`E`) needs to be "added" to the tip of master, after `C` and `D`.
- You have `master` checked out and your working tree is clean.

The history looks like this initially (the `origin` remote represents what's public, `HEAD` points to your currently checked out branch head):

```
(A)<--(B)<--(C)<--(D)
                  ^ ^
                 /   \
           master     orgin/master
                ^
                |
             HEAD
```

You need to be able to see this graph yourself. I usually use a git alias like this (`g` for "graph"):

```
git config --global alias.g "log --decorate --oneline --graph"
```

You can then get the picture above by invoking:

```
git g master origin/master
```

(That displays everything reachable from `master` and/or `origin/master`. Use `git g --all` to show everytihng.)

First create a local temporary branch head called `temp` that points to `B`, and then check it out.

```
git branch temp <SHA1 of B>
git checkout temp
```

The commit graph now looks like this:

```
       HEAD
       |
       v
       temp
       |
       v
(A)<--(B)<--(C)<--(D)
                  ^ ^
                 /   \
           master     orgin/master
```

Run your release script which tags the current commit, makes a change (probably bumping up the release number or something), and then makes a commit of that change.

```
<magic release script>
```

If I understand your release script correctly, then the resulting graph should look like this:

```
                        HEAD
                        |
                        v
                        temp
                        |
                        v
 tag: product-1.0.0    (E)
                   \   /
                    v v
              (A)<--(B)<--(C)<--(D)
                                ^ ^
                               /   \
                         master     orgin/master
```

It's now time to move back to `master` and to "carry over" the `E` commit:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <SHA1 of E>
```

The `cherry-pick` command treats a single commit as a patch. The "patch" contains the difference between the tree snapshot at `B` and the snapshot at `E`. This "patch" is then applied at whatever branch head you have checked out - in this case `master`. The changes in the patch are made into a new commit (`F`) with the same message, and author as the original one (`E`).

```
                        temp
                        |
                        v
 tag: product-1.0.0    (E)
                   \   /
                    v v
              (A)<--(B)<--(C)<--(D)<--(F)
                                 ^     ^
                                 |     |
                     origin/master     master
                                       ^
                                       |
                                       HEAD
```

Note that the `F` commit is not identical to the `E` commit! It is only "the same in spirit", that is it introduces the same logical change.

After this, review the final state and you should be ready to push the new `master` state to `origin` to make it public.

```
git push origin master:master
```

You can now remove the temporary `temp` branch head:

```
git branch -D temp
```

You usually use the `-d` option to delete a branch, but `git` won't let you use it here. The reason is that you will lose the `E` commit. In this case it is OK since we have "saved" `E` by using `cherry-pick`. As `git` considers `E` and `F` to be distinct commits it can't know that the "spirit of `E`" remains in `F` and no information would be lost. You need to tell `git` that you have made sure that you know what you are doing by using `-D` instead of `-d`.

Finally you should have:

```
    tag: product-1.0.0
                     |
                     v
              (A)<--(B)<--(C)<--(D)<--(F)
                                      ^ ^
                                     /   \
                        origin/master     master
                                          ^
                                          |
                                          HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Branch at your tag and put E on that branch and merge the branch_E back into you main branch or just cherry-pick commit E back on the main branch after D.